# Grading Group Creation in Civil 3D

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin, autocad-scripts

What is Grading Groups function in Civil 3D? Can someone point me in the right direction to understand it's proper use?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Grading groups are used to organize gradings into named collections
> for surface creation and volume computations.
>
> You can choose whether to automatically create a surface from the
> grading group, and you can identify a base surface for volume
> calculations. Once you create a surface from a grading group, you can
> use the Grading Volume Tools to adjust the elevation of the grading
> group to balance cut and fill volumes.

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/civil-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2021/ENU/Civil3D-UserGuide/files/GUID-E36190B3-533B-45A6-8409-8B8C44BDD0C0-htm.html